# how to model response variable is bounded by a predictor variable

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, random-effects-model

I have a set up like this

continuous outcome ~ categorical predictor group variable + continuous predictor

The issue is that the continuous predictor is always an lower bound on the outcome so if the continuous predictor  is -500 then the outcome can be between -500 and infinity.  What is the best model for this type of data given that my goal is to perform inference on the categorical predictor group variable and I was using a lme4 model to get random intercepts as I have 20 categorical predictors. The predicted values are falling outside the possible ranges.

Note the continous outcome can be between -infinity and infinity but for each outcome the lower bound is the continuous predictor.

Comment: I updated the question with some toy data here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305427/bounded-predictor-variable-modeling-constraint