# bounded predictor variable modeling constraint

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning

I have a model similar to below with a continuous outcome, continuous predictor and a categorical variable. the goal of this analysis is to make inferences on the group variable. The issue is that y is bounded by x in the form of y >= -x. When the model makes predictions you can see in the plot below that the predicted value is outside the possible range. See the last plot.

How can this be remedied? A custom loss function to penalize going beyond the bound and use gradient descent regression? Or is there some other way? Thank you.

```
x =   rep(seq(-10,10,1),each=5) 
y =  rep(0,length(x) )
weights = sample( seq(1,1000,1) ,length(x))
groups = rep( letters[1:5], times =length(x)/5  ) 

## the outcome y has the relationship y >= -x
for(i in 1:length(x)){
  y[i] = sample(  seq(-x[i],-x[i]+ ifelse(x[i]<0 , 
                                          sample(seq(1,10,.1),1),
                                          sample(seq(5,40,.1),1) ),1)

                      ,1)
} 

dat =data.frame(x = x, y = y, weights = weights, group = groups)
model = lm(dat = dat, y ~ x + group + group * x, weights = weights)
dat$FIT= predict(model, dat, allow.new.levels = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = x, y = y, color = group))+geom_point( aes(size = weights))+
geom_line(data = dat, aes(x = x, y = FIT, color = group))  

#data for new predictions
newdata = data.frame( x = seq(-100,100,1) , 
                      group = rep("c", length( seq(-100,100,1) )),
                      bound = -seq(-100,100,1)
                      )

## when pridicting new data the outcome y has the relationship y >= -x
## but the predicted vales are below the bound. See how red line is below blue to the left of zero
new_preds  = predict(model, newdata, allow.new.levels = TRUE)
ggplot(data = newdata, aes(x = x, y = new_preds, color = group))+geom_line()  +
  geom_line(data = newdata, aes(x = x, y = bound, color = "green"))
```

Comment: If the continuous predictor is $X$, the outcome is $Y$, and you have $Y> -X$ then let $Y^*=Y+X$. Now $Y^*$ should now be on the positive half-line; it could perhaps be modelled via a Gamma GLM or something similar (with identity link if you still want the relationship between $Y$ and $X$ to be linear), and the coefficient of the relationship with $X$ should simply be changed by one, and there should be no impact on coefficients not involving $X$. Hypothesis tests and confidence intervals should translate without much difficulty.

Comment: @Glen_b   I updated the question with some toy data of what the issue is. You can see the outcome is bounded by the predictor.  Do you have any reference papers about this?

Comment: My advice seems to be unaltered. I doubt anyone would put this kind of thing in a stats paper - and usually if you do put stuff of that level in a stats paper they just tell you to take it back out again -- it would be mentioned in passing, (e.g. "Since the lower bound is -X, we reparameterized the model to be in terms of Y+X which is positive; conclusions are described in terms of the original Y" would probably be about all that could fit in). You could make more of a deal about it in a paper for an application  area; there may be a reference in such a paper but I don't know of one.

Comment: Because this is a reworking of your previous question, I have merged the two threads in order to retain the comments, most of which still appear to be relevant.

Comment: couldn't run a bayesian model and make the liklihood of data below the bound zero?